# How to tell if a func is called?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to change the `zIndex` of an element in my `Vstack` only when a certain function is called/active.

My code is as follows;

```
Image(superReminder.image)
  .resizable()
  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
  .frame(minWidth: 0,maxWidth: .infinity,minHeight: 200,maxHeight: .infinity)
  .saturation(superReminder.pastreminder ? 0.1 : 1)
  .clipShape(Rectangle())
  .cornerRadius(10)
  .padding(.all)
  .pinchToZoom()
  //.zIndex(pinchToZoom ? 1 : 2) // SOMETHING LIKE THIS
```

`.pinchToZoom()` is the custom function I declared in another Swift file.
Is there a way to tell if the function is called or not? Or can I declare a `@State var` for the function?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a @State variable in your view, pass it to the custom function so it's changed when there's a pinch, and use that variable in .zIndex()

```
@State var isPinched: Bool = false
Image(superReminder.image)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(minWidth: 0,maxWidth: .infinity,minHeight: 200,maxHeight: .infinity)
    .saturation(superReminder.pastreminder ? 0.1 : 1)
    .clipShape(Rectangle())
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .padding(.all)
    .pinchToZoom($isPinched)
    .zIndex($isPinched ? 1 : 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I'm not there yet to pass a variable to a function I copied from somewhere else. Inspecting the funch, I realized there is 'isPinching' bool variable in the structure as copied below;
`struct PinchToZoom: ViewModifier {
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var anchor: UnitPoint = .center
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var isPinching: Bool = false`

but I can't call the variable in another view.

Comment: As the variable is not the source of truth in your PinchToZoom struct, you should use it with `@Binding`, instead of `@State`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts Damien but I think my question itself is wrong, to begin with. First of all, .pinchToZoom is a view modifier passed as an extension. I have trouble accessing its properties. Even if I could, I feel like PinchToZoom properties wouldn't reflect the true data for the view modifier added to the image in my original question. This being said, I feel like this is over my current level of understanding of Swift and I decided to change the view with some ZStacks on top of each other and make a simpler UI.